# Laravel Auth::user not found in other controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When a user is registered an email is send to the user email with an activation link (auth_code) which links to this function:

```
public function confirmUser($authentication_code)
{
    if (!$authentication_code) {
        return 'auth code not found!';
    }

    $user = User::where('authentication_code', '=', $authentication_code)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        return 'user not found!';
    }

    $user->active = 1;
    $user->save();

    Session::put('user_id', $user->id);

    Auth::login($user);

    return view('user.setpassword', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

So the user will log in.

Now there is my problem. Via the `UserConstructor` it wil lead to the `CompanyController`

```
//UserController
public function  __construct(User $user, CompaniesController $companies, UserTypeController $userType, AttributeController $attributes)
{
    $cid = Auth::user()->company_id;

    if (Auth::user()->usertype_id == 7) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    else
    {
        $array_company_ids = $companies->getCompany_ids($cid);
        $this->user = $user->whereIn('company_id', $array_company_ids);
    }

}

//CompanyController
public function __construct(Company $company)
{
    if (Auth::user()->usertype_id == 7) {
        $this->company = $company;
    } else {
        $this->company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $this->company = $company->Where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '=', $this->company_id)
                ->orWhere('parent_id', '=', $this->company_id);
        });
    }

    $this->middleware('auth');

    $page_title = trans('common.companies');
    view()->share('page_title', $page_title);
}
```

Which leads to this error: [image]

And when I do `Auth::check()` inside the CompanyController it will return false, so somehow it will log the user off in the process, what is going wrong?

(Auth::check() in the confirmUser will give true as result)

Comment: What's this `usertype_id` it's a collumn on your User table?

Comment: Usertype 1-> a customer, 2->agent, 3->employee, (7->admin) and so forth, just a type of a user (CMS)

Comment: seems like a session issue; what does Auth::check() say at the beginning of the CompanyController? and what driver do you have for session?

Comment: That will return `false` , and I use `eloquent`

Comment: What does the session look like? `var_dump(\Request::session()->all());`

Answer (score 2):

From what I read. You are instantiating the UserController with the parameter CompanyController.

This instantiation is done before you have actually send the Auth::login() call.

As you are instantiating the company controller with `__construct` before running `confirmUser` on the `userController` the object companyController exists before the `Auth::login()` call is made.

Answer (score 0):

I did send it with a hidden input field. Try to do it this way:

```
<input id="email" type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" required>
```

Mine works perfectly.