# Using a controller as an argument in another controller

Tags: php, controller

While helping [@liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4344851/liam) solve a [session/authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074295/laravel-authuser-not-found-in-other-controller/31075980), I actually mentioned using a controller as an argument (or dependancy) within another controller is bad practice.

Now in this exact issue we found out that during construct of the second controller the user was not logged in, because the login call was done after the instantiation of the first (and thus the second controller).

I've never heard of anyone using controllers this way and I cannot find any resources supporting my claim for marking it as bad practice. Apart from this single issue, do more issues exist that can be expected? I assume you can speak of division of responsibility along the lines of MVC, but how? High level and shared logic should be moved to a service layer, but how do you properly motivate stepping away from the above situation?

Not sure whether this question should be migrated to programmers and I certainly hope it's not too wide nor too opinion-based. Any assistance to keep this question open is welcome.